# WebRTC: send SDP answer without signalling server

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Is it possible to send SDP answer over RTCPeerConnection without signaling server?
Exmaple 2 shows what I am asking for.

**Example 1. WebRTC communication, when SDP answer send over signaling server.**

```
LOCAL                 Singnaling    REMOTE
peer                  service       peer
  |                      |             |
create SDP offer         |             |
send SDP offer---------->|------------>|
  |                      |     setRemoteSdp(SDP offer)
  |                      |     create SDP answer
  |<---------------------|<----send SDP answer <======
  |                      |             |
setRemoteSdp(SDP answer) |             |
create ICE candidate 1   |             |
send ICE candidate 1---->|------------>|
  |                      |     addIceCandidate(ICE 1)
create ICE candidate 2   |             |
send ICE candidate 2---->|------------>|
  |                            addIceCandidate(ICE 2)
  |                                    |
  |                            select best ICE
  |<---------------------------send REMOTE ICE over WebRTC
  |                                    |
  |<-------Peer2Peer over WebRTC------>|
```

It is mock signaling server:

```js
const signaling = {
    /** @param {string} senderId,  @param {RTCSessionDescription} sdp */
    sdpSend: (senderId, sdp) => {
        console.log(`${senderId} SDP send`);
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('sdp', {detail: {senderId, sdp} }))
    },

    /** @param {string} clientId,  @param {(sdp:RTCSessionDescription)=>void} callBack */
    sdpOnGet: (clientId, callBack) =>
        document.addEventListener('sdp', evt => {
            if (evt.detail.senderId !== clientId) {
                console.log(`${clientId} SDP onGet`);
                callBack(evt.detail.sdp)
            }
        }),

    /** @param {string} senderId,  @param {RTCIceCandidate} candidate */
    iceCandidateSend: (senderId, candidate) => {
        console.log(`${senderId} iceCandidate send`);
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('ice', {detail: {senderId, candidate} }))
    },

    /** @param {string} clientId,  @param {(candidate:RTCIceCandidate)=>void} callBack */
    iceCandidateOnGet: (clientId, callBack) =>
        document.addEventListener('ice', evt => {
            if (evt.detail.senderId !== clientId) {
                console.log(`${clientId} iceCandidate onGet`);
                callBack(evt.detail.candidate);
            }
        })
};
```

Here is working code

```js
//
// remote peer
{
    const remoteClientId = 'REMOTE';

    const remoteCon = new RTCPeerConnection();
    remoteCon.ondatachannel = evt => {
        console.log('REMOTE ondatachannel');
        const channel = evt.channel;
        channel.onopen = (event) => {
            console.log('REMOTE channel onopen');

            const msg = 'Hi from remote';
            console.log(`REMOTE message send: ${msg}`);
            channel.send(msg);
        };
        channel.onmessage = (event) => {
            console.log('REMOTE onmessage:', event.data);
        };
    };

    signaling.iceCandidateOnGet(remoteClientId, async candidate => 
        await remoteCon.addIceCandidate(candidate));

    signaling.sdpOnGet(remoteClientId, async sdpOffer => {
        await remoteCon.setRemoteDescription(sdpOffer);
        await remoteCon.setLocalDescription();
        signaling.sdpSend(remoteClientId, remoteCon.localDescription);
    });
}

//
// local peer
{
    const localClientId = 'LOCAL';

    const localCon = new RTCPeerConnection();
    const localChannel = localCon.createDataChannel('chat');
    localChannel.onopen = evt => {
        console.log('LOCAL channel onopen');

        const msg = 'Hi from local';
        console.log(`LOCAL message send: ${msg}`);
        localChannel.send(msg);
    };
    localChannel.onmessage = evt =>
        console.log('LOCAL onmessage:', evt.data);  

    signaling.sdpOnGet(localClientId, async sdpRemote => {
        await localCon.setRemoteDescription(sdpRemote);

        localCon.onicecandidate = evt => {
            if (evt.candidate) {
                signaling.iceCandidateSend(localClientId, evt.candidate);
            }
        }
    });

    // SDP
    // creates and sets SDP
    await localCon.setLocalDescription();
    signaling.sdpSend(localClientId, localCon.localDescription);
}
```

Console ouput:

```
LOCAL SDP send
REMOTE SDP onGet
REMOTE SDP send
LOCAL SDP onGet
LOCAL iceCandidate send
REMOTE iceCandidate onGet
LOCAL channel onopen
LOCAL message send: Hi from local
REMOTE ondatachannel
REMOTE channel onopen
REMOTE message send: Hi from remote
REMOTE onmessage: Hi from local
LOCAL onmessage: Hi from remote
```

**Example 2. WebRTC communication, when SDP answer send over WebRTC**
What I am asking for.

As I understand:
LOCAL peer can create SDP, collect all ICE Candidates, and send all at once to REMOTE peer over Signaling Server.
REMOTE peer know SDP offer and ICE Candidates -> can send SDP answer over WebRTC.

```
LOCAL                 Singnaling    REMOTE
peer                  service       peer
  |                      |             |
create SDP offer         |             |
create ICE candidate 1   |             |
create ICE candidate 2   |             |
  |                      |             |
send SDP, ICE1 , ICE 2-->|------------>|
  |                            setRemoteSdp(SDP offer)
  |                            create SDP answer
  |                            addIceCandidate(ICE 1)
  |                            addIceCandidate(ICE 2)
  |                            select best ICE
  |<---------------------------send SDP answer, ICEs over WebRTC
  |                                    |
  |<-------Peer2Peer over WebRTC------>|
```

singnaling service:

```js
const signaling = {
    /** @param {string} senderId,  @param {RTCSessionDescription} sdp, @param {RTCIceCandidate} iceCandidates */
    sdpAndIceChannelsSend: (senderId, sdp, iceCandidates) => {
        console.log(`${senderId} SDP and ICECandidates send`);
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('sdpAndIce', {detail: { senderId, sdp, iceCandidates } }));
    },

    /** @param {string} clientId,  @param {(sdp:RTCSessionDescription, iceCandidates:RTCIceCandidate[])=>void} callBack */
    sdpAndIceChannelsOnGet: (clientId, callBack) =>
        document.addEventListener('sdpAndIce', evt => {
            if (evt.detail.senderId !== clientId) {
                console.log(`${clientId} SDP and iceCandidates onGet`);
                callBack(evt.detail.sdp, evt.detail.iceCandidates);
            }
        }),
};
```

Not working code

```js
//
// remote peer
{
    const remoteClientId = 'REMOTE';

    const remoteCon = new RTCPeerConnection();
    remoteCon.ondatachannel = evt => {
        console.log('REMOTE ondatachannel');
        const channel = evt.channel;
        channel.onopen = (event) => {
            console.log('REMOTE channel onopen');

            // send message to LOCAL
            const msg = 'Hi from remote';
            console.log(`REMOTE message send: ${msg}`);
            channel.send(msg);
        };
        channel.onmessage = (event) => {
            console.log('REMOTE onmessage:', event.data);
        };
    };

    signaling.sdpAndIceChannelsOnGet(remoteClientId, async (sdpOffer, iceCandidates) => {
        await remoteCon.setRemoteDescription(sdpOffer);
        await remoteCon.setLocalDescription();

        for(const iceCandidate of iceCandidates)
            await remoteCon.addIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
    });
}

//
// local peer
{
    const localClientId = 'LOCAL';

    const localCon = new RTCPeerConnection();
    const localChannel = localCon.createDataChannel('chat');
    localChannel.onopen = evt => {
        console.log('LOCAL channel onopen');

        // send message to REMOTE
        const msg = 'Hi from local';
        console.log(`LOCAL message send: ${msg}`);
        localChannel.send(msg);
    };
    localChannel.onmessage = evt =>
        console.log('LOCAL onmessage:', evt.data);  

    // SDP
    // creates and sets SDP
    await localCon.setLocalDescription();

    const iceCandidates = [];
    localCon.onicecandidate = evt => {
        if (evt.candidate) {
            iceCandidates.push(evt.candidate);
        } else {
            // all ice candidates getted
            // send SDP and iceCandidates to REMOTE
            signaling.sdpAndIceChannelsSend(localClientId,
                localCon.localDescription, iceCandidates);
        }
    }
}
```

Console ouput:

```
LOCAL SDP and ICECandidates send
REMOTE SDP and iceCandidates onGet
```

Comment: From my understanding to establish a connection between both peers, they have to exchange the ICE first.

Comment: You cannot send data to another peer because the connection hasn't been made.